# Is it possible to post data when connectivity is established when an app is in the background?

Tags: xamarin.forms, background-process

Let's say an app caches a post request when there's no internet connection and the app is backgrounded.

Is this state and upon establishing network connectivity, can the app be roused such that it can complete the cached requests?

Comment: iOS or Android?

Comment: @apineda Both. It's a cross platform app.

Comment: You can do it using Background Services.